# current_path with haml and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I would like to add a css class:landing-page when a user is on the root_path. I am using haml.

```
%body
  ={:class => "landing-page" if current_page?(root_path)}
```

I am getting a syntax error, any ideas on how this should actually should be?

**UPDATE:**
I did this and it work for me:

```
%body{:class => "normal-page#{current_page?(root_path) ? 'landing-page' : ''}"}
```

Comment: To which element do you want to apply the class?

Comment: nm. you want to apply it to body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-body_class = current_page?(root_path) ? "landing-page" : ""
%body{:class => body_class}
```